# Ingress hosts not showing up in Kubernetes GUI

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed one app to Kubernetes, but I am not seeing the Ingress hosts in the GUI
[image]

Expecting something like below, what could be wrong?
[image]

Comment: Well, if you have kubectl then just list it using `kubectl get ingress`

Comment: I am using helm for deployment

Comment: Don't you see them only in GUI or at all ? Did you try to list them first as suggested above ? If they don't appear there's nothing wrong with GUI and apparently they've not been correctly deployed.

Comment: Yes, Don't see only on GUI, with the above command able to see in the terminal.

Comment: ok, could you provide detailed instruction how to reproduce this issue from A to Z ? Are you sure that ingresses listed in your GUI don't belong only to a particular namespace ? Any option of changing it and displaying resources in other namespaces ? Does it happen only with this app deployed with helm ? What about a simple nginx ingress Deployment, you can also expose it via ingress for testing purpose and check if it appears in dashboard.